# Change attribute characters with XSLT within tag with other character

Tags: xml, xslt

Can i use XSLT to change specific characters within attribute to characters of my own within XML.

I have this XML

```
.... some data ....
<book attribute"test1/test2.test3"></book>
.... some data ...
<book attribute"test4/test5.test6"></book>
... some data ...
```

Now i would like to change characters "/" and "." to "_", but only on tags book. After transformation i would need XML written like

```
.... some data ....
<book attribute"test1_test2_test3"></book>
.... some data ...
<book attribute"test4_test5_test6"></book>
... some data ...
```

Can this be done simply,
Thanks,
eoglasi

Comment: Start from the "identity template" and then define a specific template for `book/@attribute`, exactly the same principle as I suggested in [my answer to your last question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19933329/592139).

Answer (score 2):

This XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="book/@attribute">
    <xsl:attribute name="attribute">
      <xsl:value-of select="translate(.,'./','__')"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

copies everything in the input XML 'as is' except the attribute `attribute` in the element `book`, whose value is converted changing slashes and dots to underscore.

You can change the XPath `book/@attribute` to match any other attributes that need to be converted in the same way - e.g. `book/@attribute|person/@url` to match also the attribute `url` in the element `person`.

Comment: This works like a charm. What about if i have space in attribute?

Comment: I don't understand the question - how are spaces special? Do you want to get rid of them?

Comment: Lets say i have attribute named Test 2.3/4, how i would replace also space so i would get Test_2_3_4? Thanks, eoglasi

Comment: Attribute names cannot contain spaces

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with the `translate()` function of XSLT. For an explanation of this function, see for example http://zvon.org/xxl/XSLTreference/Output/function_translate.html.

The general syntax is this:

```
translate('eoglasi', 'ae', 'AE')
```

Which results in

```
'EoglAsi'
```